# Double-column listing package

Tags: listings, two-column

Not too well up on LaTeX, but I want to use the `listings` package for listings *spanning* a two-column format.

Unfortunately, asterisks cannot save me (like for figures/tables); this doesn't work:

```
\begin{lstlisting*}
...
\end{lstlisting*}
```

I've Googled about, but got no satisfactory answer, and getting a bit desperate. Should be simple... hope I'm not missing something stupid. Perhaps it's possible to embed this into a separate spanning float?

Help?

(P.S., I've posted this on the main stackoverflow site as well... https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3744232/edit if this is considered a duplicate, please comment and I'll remove the other. Getting a bit desperate fighting a deadline.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is in the listings documentation.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[float=*]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: So simple :). Many thanks for that. I had scanned the listings documentation a few times and had missed it (was rushing for a deadline). I had also scanned a few forums. In the end, managed to fit the listing in one column with 'tiny' font... not ideal, but now I know for future.