# Two column code listings in appendix in a one column report

Tags: formatting, two-column, appendices

How do I place a two column appendix in a single column report? I want it so that at the beginning of the appendix I'm in single column mode, then I want to place some source code listings in 2 column format within my appendix.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the code will fit in two column typesetting?

Comment: For anyone looking for the opposite, it is solved [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/double-column-listing-package).

Answer (score 23):

For multi-column typesetting of listings the `listings` package provides the `multicols=n` option, which in fact is  a built-in interface to the `multicol` package.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{listings,multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=3em, multicols=2]
First line.
Second line.
Third line.
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to load `multicol` explicitly with `\usepackage{multicol}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the package `multicol` or you can switch your document via `\twocolumn` in the new mode:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=3em]
First line.
Second line.
Third line.
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\twocolumn
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=3em]
First line.
Second line.
Third line.
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
Next line.
Next Line
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the standard report class, you may use `\twocolumn` to switch to two column mode:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\appendix
\twocolumn
\chapter{Here and now! The two column listing}
\lstinputlisting[{language=[LaTeX]TeX},breaklines=true]{\jobname.tex}

\onecolumn
\chapter{One more chapter in one column mode}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

But with this, you may not have additional one column text after the `\chapter`. With KOMA-Script `\chapter` may be used inside the optional argument of `\twocolumn`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\appendix
\twocolumn[%
  \chapter{Here and now! The two column listing}
  \blindtext

  \vspace*{\baselineskip}
]


\lstinputlisting[{language=[LaTeX]TeX},breaklines=true]{\jobname.tex}

\onecolumn
\chapter{One more chapter in one column mode}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

But there's a alround suggestion for the standard classes too: [multicol](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\appendix
\chapter{Here and now! The two column listing}
\blindtext

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lstinputlisting[{language=[LaTeX]TeX},breaklines=true]{\jobname.tex}
\end{multicols}

\chapter{One more chapter in one column mode}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

And this is indeed the same like

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\appendix
\chapter{Here and now! The two column listing}
\blindtext

\lstinputlisting[{language=[LaTeX]TeX},breaklines=true,multicols=2]{\jobname.tex}

\chapter{One more chapter in one column mode}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Note, that if you are using option `multicols` you have to load package multicol. Package listings does not load multicol itself!

For more information about `\begin{multicols}{…}[…]` please have a look at the package manual.