# lstlisting in two columns

Tags: listings, minipage

I would like to have two listings, side by side.

They have approximately the same length, therefore I don't care about how it's layed out if one part is longer.

I tried

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk{\begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 1,frame=tlrb]{Name}
void code()
{

}
\end{lstlisting}}

\colchunk{\begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 2,frame=tlrb]{Name}
void code()
{

}
\end{lstlisting}}

\colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}
\end{minipage}
```

while the border of the listings end up in chunks as follows:
[image: chunked listing]

Btw I'm using the texlive-package & `pdflatex` on Ubuntu and the document class is

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
twoside,
openright,
notitlepage,
parskip=half,
]{scrreprt}
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use two `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
twoside,
openright,
notitlepage,
parskip=half,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 1,frame=tlrb]{Name}
void code()
{

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 2,frame=tlrb]{Name}
void code()
{

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A+1: great. exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot!

Comment: As described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34098/two-column-code-listings-in-appendix-in-a-one-column-report), `listings` has an option for spreading a listing over two columns. It is not exactly what the OP asks for, but noted here for posterity.

Comment: Use `\begin{lstlisting}[t]` if you want the two `lstlisting's` **not** to be vertically centered if they are of uneven length.

Comment: If you need `lstlistings` to be centered top, then you need to use `\begin{minipage}[t]`

Comment: This numbers the listing from 1 to 8 across the two columns.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer you just need to change one of the Listings name (both have name "Name")

Comment: Using your solution, I got the error "Not in outer par mode" when using the WileyNJD-v2 template :(