# Listing with two columns in a single fancy frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, color, framed, colortbl

I am playing a little with [`lstlistings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) and I wonder whether such a thing would be achievable for all my listings:

[image: listing]

How to achieve this kind of things?

Note : I am searching for a solution I can apply to all my listings (by defining a new command for example), and which will automatically balance the two columns...

Comment: Use a tabular.  You will also need packages tblcolor and colorx if you want colors.

Comment: I'd have a look at `tcolorbox`

Comment: You could also do it with Tikz or \fbox, \makebox and two minipages.  I suppose you want a command to do all the work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`listings` package can interact nicely with the `multicol` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34103/8425). The frame stuff is done with the help of `tcolorbox` which, in turn, plays nicely with `listings`. It seems to be transitive!

The idea to highlight the numbers is taken from [Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176462/8425).

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings}
\newtcblisting{mycpptwocol}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  arc = 0pt,
  outer arc = 0pt,
  colback = blue!5,
  colframe = blue!50!black,
  listing only,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
  listing options = {%
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    multicols = 2,
    numbers = left,
    xleftmargin = 1em,
    showstringspaces = false,
  },
  overlay = {%
    \fill[gray!30] 
      (interior.north west)
      rectangle 
      ([xshift = 2em]interior.south west);
    \fill[gray!30] 
      ([xshift = -1em]interior.north)
      rectangle 
      ([xshift = 1em]interior.south);
    \draw[ultra thick, blue!50!black]
      ([xshift = -1em]interior.north) -- 
      ([xshift = -1em]interior.south); 
  },
  /utils/exec = {%
    \def\thelstnumber{%
      \texttt{\csname two@digits\endcsname{\the\value{lstnumber}}}}},
  title = {\centering\ttfamily #1}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{mycpptwocol}[helloworld.cpp]
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World``;
    return 0;
}
// This is a second column, just
// for fun !!!
\end{mycpptwocol}
\end{document}
```

***EDIT*** As requested, a version with two leading zeros. FYI, `\two@digits` is a `LaTeX` core macro (see `texdoc source2e`) and `\three@digits` does not exist (so I define it, but you may again have some issue with `\makeatletter`).

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings}
\makeatletter
\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1<10 00\else\ifnum#1<100 0\fi\fi\number#1}
\makeatother
\newtcblisting{mycpptwocol}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  arc = 0pt,
  outer arc = 0pt,
  colback = blue!5,
  colframe = blue!50!black,
  listing only,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
  listing options = {%
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    multicols = 2,
    numbers = left,
    xleftmargin = 1.5em,
    showstringspaces = false,
  },
  overlay = {%
    \fill[gray!30] 
      (interior.north west)
      rectangle 
      ([xshift = 2.5em]interior.south west);
    \fill[gray!30] 
      ([xshift = -1em]interior.north)
      rectangle 
      ([xshift = 1.5em]interior.south);
    \draw[ultra thick, blue!50!black]
      ([xshift = -1em]interior.north) -- 
      ([xshift = -1em]interior.south); 
  },
  /utils/exec = {%
    \def\thelstnumber{%
      \texttt{\csname three@digits\endcsname{\the\value{lstnumber}}}}},
  title = {\centering\ttfamily #1}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{mycpptwocol}[helloworld.cpp]
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World``;
    return 0;
}
// This is a second column, just
// for fun !!!
//
\end{mycpptwocol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! And how to be able to put the title as a parameter (because the title will be different for each listing) ?

Comment: @Vincent Put `\newtcblisting{mycpptwocol}[1][]{` and replace `title=...` with `#1` in the definition of `mycpptwocol`and use `\begin{mycpptwocol}[title = {\centering\ttfamily helloworld.cpp}]`

Comment: One last question : In my code \makeatletter
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{%
  \texttt{\two@digits{\the\value{lstnumber}}}}
\makeatletter` fails with the message `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1`. Any idea ?

Comment: @Vincent See my edit (you should not have problem anymore). I also integrated Harish's idea (thanks).

Comment: @cjorssen And one last thing (and I validate your answer): I would like to have 3 digits of lstnumber and replacing \two by \three does not work...

Comment: @Vincent See my edit.

Comment: @cjorssen Validated! Thanks for your amazing work! Following questions on alignments here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176533/aligning-and-centering-a-lstlisting-with-two-columns-on-a-page