# How to add vertical line next to code numbers and change background colors

Tags: listings, pseudocode

I am using the `listings` package. With the code below I get a result like this
[image]

I want to draw a line next to the line numbers like below.
[image]

Also if possible I would like to change the background color of the line numbers.

The code I'm using is like below

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
    frame=single,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    framexleftmargin=1.5em,
    xleftmargin=2em,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple}
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
for j=2 to A.length
    key=A[j]
    i=j-1
    while i>0 and A[i]>key
        A[i+1]=A[i]
        i=i-1
    A[i+1]=key
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This may be at least partially helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176462/218142

Answer (score 1):

1. I propose to use the package tcolorbox for the frame.
2. The instructions in \lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
3. %frame=single,
   %framexleftmargin=1.5em,
   %xleftmargin=2em,
   %backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour}
   are no more use
4. The background color for the number is for example
   \colorlet{mycodebacknum}{gray!70}

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \usepackage{tcolorbox}
   \tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable}

   \definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
   \definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
   \definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
   \definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

   \lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
       basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
       escapeinside={(*}{*)},
       %frame=single,
       breakatwhitespace=false,         
       breaklines=true,                 
       captionpos=b,                    
       keepspaces=true,
       showspaces=false,                
       showstringspaces=false,
       showtabs=false,                  
       tabsize=2,
       numbers=left,
       numbersep=5pt,
       %framexleftmargin=1.5em,
       %xleftmargin=2em,
       %backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
       commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
       keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
       numberstyle=\color{codegray},
       stringstyle=\color{codepurple}
   }
   \lstset{style=mystyle}

   \colorlet{mycodebacktitre}{backcolour}
   \colorlet{mycodebacktrait}{gray!70}
   \colorlet{mycodebacknum}{gray!70}
   \newtcolorbox{mycode}[1]{
       %
       breakable,
       hbox boxed title,
       enhanced,
       colbacktitle=mycodebacktitre,
       fonttitle=\bfseries,
       coltitle=black,
       attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
       %    
       colback=mycodebacktitre,
       colframe=mycodebacktrait,
       %
       title={#1},
       overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[mycodebacknum] (frame.south west)
       rectangle ([xshift=1.5em]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}% pour colorer la zone numéro}
   }
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \begin{document}
   \begin{mycode}{title}
       \begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
   for j=2 to A.length
       key=A[j]
       i=j-1
       while i>0 and A[i]>key
           A[i+1]=A[i]
           i=i-1
       A[i+1]=key
   \end{lstlisting}
   \end{mycode}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]